# Jira query to find issues without links

Tags: jira

I'd like a JQL query to find all issues in a project which are not linked to anything else (links = empty). Using Jira 6.4.12. As far as I can see this isn't possible. Tell me I'm missing something and it's do'able?

Googling says it's possible with plug-ins - but that's probably a non-starter this end.

Anyone?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Jira doesn't provide this feature.

The easiest way to do this would be to install a script runner addon (you can get it for free). Once you install it, you will have new JQL functions.
In the issue navigator, go to basic mode and type the following:

```
issueFunction in linkedIssuesOf("project = FOO") and project = FOO
```

If you do not have the access to the addon section you can do next:

Go to issue navigator, switch to list view, click on "columns" button and search for "linked issues" and select it.

Comment: The sample issue query returns the ones with links right? The op is asking ones without links. Small correction maybe.

Comment: You can do an extract of all issues, an extract of issues with links and then simply use the features in excel to leave all issues without links.  Not ideal but would work.